# Function $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ in $\mathcal C^2$ s.t. $(a,b)$ is a stationary point but the Hessian matrix not diagonalizable.

Tags: real-analysis

Is there function $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ in $\mathcal C^2$ s.t. $(a,b)$ is a stationnary point but s.t. $H(a,b)$ (the evalutation of the hessian matrix in $(a,b)$) is not diagonalisable ?

I'm asking this question because in my course it's written that if $(a,b)$ is a stationnary point, then it's either a minimum, a maximum or a saddle point. And to check this, I always compute the eigenvalue of the hessian matrix, and magically, I always have two (ore sometimes just one, but it's a double positive or negative but I can conclude on the positivity or negativity of the hessian matrix).

But can we have an hessian matrix with no eigenvalue or with only 0 eigenvalue ? like an hessian matrix s.t. the caracteristic polynomial would be $x^2+1$ or $x^2$ ? If yes, what would be $(a,b)$ ? If not, why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^2$ we have that $f_{xy}=f_{yx}.$ That is, the Hessian matrix is symmetric. And, the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are real.